# How to effectively compare a lot of photos to find duplicates

Tags: c#, image, photo

Recently I found a lot of old photos. I decided to do a small fun project, but I cannot find a way to do it effectively. I wanted to make a program (preferably in C# or java) that will take these pictures and find duplicates. I don't really want to use simple if(photo1.dateOfCreation == photo2.dateOfCreation).
Browsing through the Internet I found something like that:
- simplify photo to 16x16 bitmap
- greyscale it
- if pixel brightness > 0,5 then mark it as True (or 1), otherwise it's false (0)
- do this for all photos
- compare outcomes with some margin of error
I tried it, but it takes a lot of time (I did this on ~20 photos, but I have a few thousands of them, also storing this much information requires quite a lot of space).
It's worth noting, that pictures may have different resolutions or may contain noises, but I still want to classify them as 'the same'

Comment: Complete books are written on this subject, there is no simple answer. I don't understand however why the simplistic approach you suggested is slow or takes up a lot of space. Perhaps you should outline your implementation and focus your question on understanding why that particular approach is inefficient for you.

Comment: _I decided to do a small fun project_ LOL..